# Selenium: Firefox showing different behavior when launched by Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium, extjs

Note - App coded in Extjs
Certain ExtJs elements or parts of elements (like titles) are not appearing or loading when using the selenium launched FF.

Things I tried

1. Going to the same page with a manually launched firefox - works
2. Stopping the test after login to use the launched version and going
   to the same with issues - still see issues
3. Updated to latest version of FF - same issues.

Is there anything with the Firefox driver in selenium that could be causing these discrepancies?

To add to to the situation I can actually get the store behind the grid that isn't loading up

Comment: What version of ff and selenium are you using?

Comment: Firefox 37.0.1 ( I was previously using 35~ and still had the same issues and Selenium 2.45.0 .Net build

Answer (score 0):

The thing is ExtJS is using a really annoying HTML5 features, which need a bit more then simple simulations of user interactions. For ecample an element could be with no childs, but when you will click on it, it will automatically load all of it's childs. That's why you don't see all the elements. 
For that purposes, if you are using java you should use http://html5robot.com or similar things, which are developed to help Webdriver interact with complex HTML5 solutions.

Comment: Hey Stanjer, thanks for the reply. The problem is even when i'm manually going to the page (after selenium kicks off firefox and I stop the test) I still see the same behavior. We actually get around a lot of the dynamic loading with Ext's Component Query

Comment: Then I guess it's not really only Selenium-related problem :)

Comment: I think it is because when I launch firefox manually (vs let selenium launch.. stop the test.. use the firefox window selenium launched) it works fine